# What is the use of "ADD CX,0F830H" in 8086 system date assembly language program

Tags: assembly, x86-16, processor

To get the date from the system we use

```
mov ah,2ah
int 21h
```

**`ADD CX,0F830H`**  is used for the year part in the code.
What does the hexadecimal number 0F830h has to do with the year part here?

What is the significance of `add cx,0f830h` ?

Source for the code- https://github.com/kingspp/8086-MicroProcessor/blob/master/Date-Program.asm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a confusing way of writing `sub cx, 2000`, which in turn is done to get the last two digits of the year as the comment says later.

Comment: It says in the comment :To negate the effects of 16bit value
How does subtracting 2000 from it yields the last two digit of year? can you explain it in detail?

Comment: Obviously subtracting 2000, from say, 2017 will give you 17. This assumes the current year is between 2000 and 2099.